# How to make python reply only if you say "hi"

Tags: python, input

I want to make a thing that starts off saying hello, then you have to say hi, and then it says hey there. If you don't it tells you to say hi.

```
hello = input('Hello')

def hiOrHey(hello):
    if hello == 'hi':
        if True:
            print("Hey there!")
    else:
        print("SAY HI")
```

But, it doesn't work, it just says "Hello!", and leaves a blank line.

Comment: You are defining a function `hiOrHey()` that you never call. Try adding the line: `hiOrHey(hello)`

Comment: It says Hello and leaves a blank line because it is waiting for an input, as you asked it to do...

Comment: That line `if True:` doesn't really add any useful functionality to your code.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the help, I'm kinda new to python so, just trying to understand the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You never call your function
2. You do not need to check `if True` after already checking if the values match, that is redundant.

The following should help you get started.

```
def hiOrHey(hello):
    if hello.lower() == 'hi': # Check if hello in lowercase matches hi
        print("Hey there!")
    else:
        print("SAY HI")

hello = input('Say Hi: ')

hiOrHey(hello) # Call your function, passing variable hello
```

Comment: Thank so so much for telling me my mistakes, as I'm learning python, and I'm new to it, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

are you calling your function hiOrHey.

if not then call it.

```
def hiOrHey(hello): 
    if hello == 'hi':
        print("Hey there!") 
    else: 
        print("SAY HI")
hello = input('Hello')
hiOrHey(hello)
```

Comment: oh i used to wanted it to be hi and hey, but i forgot to change that, sorry. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

```
def hiOrHey(hello):
    if hello == 'hi':
        print("Hey there!")
    else:
        print("SAY HI")
hello = input('Hello')

hiOrHey(hello)
```

You can call your python file with: "python *filename*.py" in your command line.